# Visual studio Vb.net | Usb detection code partially working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, nullreferenceexception

I had to re-write the post because stackoverflow detects the post as already solved in another thread and i had to delete it. But the thread that referenced the forum was for C# and in anycase even reading it I can't find out a solution for my problem.

So, hello again guys :D

I did find somewhere online a code that allows me to detect usb devices and relative files,
it works but not very well because each time i plug or unplug the usb device i get:

"System.NullReferenceException", i will not write the rest of the error to avoid that stackoverflow closes the thread, anyway you should have understood my issue.

**Here the code:**

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
#Region "USB EVENT"

    Private WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219

    Public Enum WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS As Integer
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = &H19
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = &H18
        DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = &H8006
        DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = &H8000
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = &H8001
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = &H8002
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = &H8004
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = &H8003
        DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = &H8005
        DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = &H7
        DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = &H17
        DBT_USERDEFINED = &HFFFF
    End Enum

    Private Structure DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
        Public dbcv_size As Int32
        Public dbcv_devicetype As Int32
        Public dbcv_reserved As Int32
        Public dbcv_unitmask As Int32
        Public dbcv_flags As Int16
    End Structure

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

        Try
            If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then

                Dim Volume As DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

                Volume = DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)), DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)

                If Not GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask).ToString.Trim = String.Empty Then

                    Dim DriveLetter As String = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & ":\")

                    Select Case m.WParam

                        Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL

                            LblUSB.Text = DriveLetter

                            GetFiles()
                            MsgBox("Usb connected")
                            '   Code When add USB

                        Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE

                            LblUSB.Text = ""

                            CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
                            MsgBox("Usb disconnected")
                            '   Code When Remove USB

                    End Select

                End If

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        MyBase.WndProc(m)

    End Sub

    Private Function GetDriveLetterFromMask(ByRef Unit As Int32) As Char
        For i As Integer = 0 To 25
            If Unit = (2 ^ i) Then
                Return Chr(Asc("A") + i)
            End If
        Next
        Return ""
    End Function

#End Region

    Sub GetFiles()

        Try

            Dim Path = LblUSB.Text

            Dim LstFiles = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Path, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)

            For Each File In LstFiles
            Dim F As New IO.FileInfo(File)
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(F.Name)
        Next

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

**The System.NullReferenceException i get is at this point:**

```
 Volume = DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)), DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)
```

I did read that this error happens when the value is null and there should be a value associated,
i tried different approaches but none did work and i hope that someone of you could give me a solution and an explaination to better understand that.

Thank you very much guys for the help!

Comment: I did solve this by using CType instead of using DirectCast. Even if i solved my problem i would like to hear some of you better understand it. Thank you guys

Comment: The code assumes that every WM_DEVICECHANGE message applies to a volume.  That's clearly wrong and causes the exception.  You'll at least get two messages, one for the device itself (DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE) and one for the volume (DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME).  Only the latter one will let you obtain the volume letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one runs the code in VS 2019, beneath the `System.NullReferenceException` it states: *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(...) returned Nothing* which occurs because `m.LParam` is `0`. This can be observed by placing the following code just before the DirectCast statement:
`Debug.WriteLine($"m.LParam: '{m.LParam.ToString()}'")`.

There isn't a need to attempt to get a drive letter until it's been detected that the USB device has been inserted. If one refactors the code as shown below, the issue doesn't occur:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        Debug.WriteLine($"m.LParam: '{m.LParam.ToString()}'")

        Select Case CInt(m.WParam)
            Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
                Debug.WriteLine($"    DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL")

                Dim Volume As DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

                Volume = DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)), DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)

                If Not GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask).ToString.Trim = String.Empty Then

                    Dim DriveLetter As String = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & ":\")

                    LblUSB.Text = DriveLetter

                    GetFiles()
                    MsgBox("Usb connected")
                    '   Code When add USB
                End If

            Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE

                LblUSB.Text = ""

                CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
                MsgBox("Usb disconnected")
                '   Code When Remove USB

        End Select
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

A side note: It's recommended to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for your project.

---

**Update**:

After enabling [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement), one receives the following compiler error: `BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Char'` in function `GetDriveLetterFromMask` because of the statement: `Return ""`. To fix the issue, try one of the following:

**Option 1**:

```
Private Function GetDriveLetterFromMask(ByRef Unit As Int32) As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To 25
        If Unit = (2 ^ i) Then
            Return Chr(Asc("A") + i)
        End If
    Next

    Return ""
End Function
```

**Option 2**:

```
Private Function GetDriveLetterFromMask(ByRef Unit As Int32) As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To 25
        If Unit = (2 ^ i) Then
            Return Chr(Asc("A") + i)
        End If
    Next

    Return Chr(0)
End Function
```

---

**Resources**:

- [Marshal.PtrToStructure Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure)
- [DirectCast Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator)
- [CType Function (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function)

Comment: The proper solution! Thank you a lot user9938! I understood the problem thank to your comment. 

Side note: It works well without, but when i enable Option Strict i get an error in the code on "return "" here:    Private Function GetDriveLetterFromMask(ByRef Unit As Int32) As Char
            For i As Integer = 0 To 25
                If Unit = (2 ^ i) Then
                    Return Chr(Asc("A") + i)
                End If
            Next
            Return ""
        End Function